# How can I rollback a failed update in apt-get?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, rollback, apt-get

I am working on an embedded device running Ubuntu 14. The main application, let's call it **A**, can automatically update itself through apt-get. We've created a private apt repository where we publish our releases.

This main application, **A**, has some dependencies (also published in our repository), declared with Pre-Depends in the debian package.

Let's say **A** version 1.1 has the following:

```
Pre-Depends: B (= 1.0.2), C (= 2.1)
```

With this, **A** won't be updated if any of the dependencies installation fails. But the other dependencies will be updated and installed.

Let's assume dependency **B** can't be installed, for whatever reason. **C** will be updated to 2.1 and **A** won't be updated.

Since dependencies of **A**'s previous version were:

```
Pre-Depends: B (= 1.0.0), C (= 2.0)
```

the current state of **A**, and thus of the device, is broken.

Which would be the best approach in order to rollback this failed update? Or what other actions would be recommended in such scenarios?

I've found this post: https://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/debian-linux/ubuntu-linux-rollback-an-apt-get-upgrade/ where it's explained how to do a rollback, but I'd like to explore other options, if possible, since it has to be done automatically on the device.